# Web based mail that works on Windows and Linux and supports mbox

Tags: windows, linux, email, web, mbox

I am looking for a locally hosted web based mail client that will work on Windows (Vista and up) as well as Linux. Right now, I use mutt (Cygwin mutt on Windows), but I was wondering if there was a simple web based client I could use. It does not need all of the fancy features of mutt, just the ability to send mail and allow me to browse my local mbox files.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [**Squirrel Mail**](http://www.squirrelmail.org/), which is provided by my web hoster.

Alternatively, you could [use **Gmail** to manage your own personal email](http://browserland.com/how-to/use-gmail-as-a-web-based-email-client/).

Comment: Not what I am looking for. All of my mail across four different accounts is downloaded to my computer into mbox files. I need a locally hosted solution that runs in any web browser.

Comment: then install Apache and php and then Squirrel Mail. Or Alpha mail if you like Gmail layout

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Mail2web](http://mail2web.com/)?  I used to use it quite often.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.